# タグの提案: タグが現在無い質問用のタグの作成

Tags: 討議

現在、スタックオーバーフローにはタグを作成出来る人がそう多く居ません(数えてはいませんが、100人よりは少ないでしょう)

ここで問題なのは、現在無いタグを付けるべき質問をする際に、権限が無い人間はどうすれば良いかという事です。

そこで、必要なタグが無いという事を示すタグが必要だと考えています。
これは以下の利点があると考えています

- タグ作成が可能な人間が見つけやすい
- 質問者がどのタグを付けるか悩まず済む
- 関係のない(もしくは薄い)タグを付けずに済む

意見を聞かせてください。

追記として他の案を考えてみました。

- タグが合っているか不安(もしくは経験者のタグが合っているかのレビューが欲しい)というタグ
- サイトの機能として、上記のタグのような物を作る

前者ならば、SO初心者の人にも優しく、なおかつタグ無しという文化を作らないで経験者(権限持ち等)の注意を引く事が出来ると思います。対象もただタグが無いというよりも大きいため、形骸化する事がないかと思います(周知は必要かと思いますが)

後者は言ってみただけで、サイトの機能としてあれば嬉しいよねという話です。コストも高いでしょうし、一応記述はしていますが、本気では無いです。

SOの文化には慣れてないので、もしもこのような考え(初心者向けタグを新しく作る事)や適切なタグが無かったらメタで提案するのが原則という場合は取り下げるので、その場合は言ってもらえると嬉しいです。

Comment: [Meta SEの類似する提案](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113221/a-tag-that-is-a-request-for-a-new-tag)

Answer (score 7):

タグが増えていけば解決する問題なので、導入には反対です。

タグが少ないうちは機能するかもしれませんが、タグが充実した状態でこの「タグ無し」タグがあるとノイズにしかならないと思います。かといって一度導入したタグを後から禁止するというのも難しいでしょう。

また、タグが少ない間は基本的に質問自体も少ないはずなので、「タグ作成が可能な人間が見つけやすい」というメリットはあまりないと思います。

Comment: この通りです。自然に増えるものですが、「なしでいい」という文化を最初から作れば、後にそれをなくすのが大変になるとおもいます。とりあえず、必要なタグがなかったら、メタで投稿してください。権限があれば、編集にて適切なタグも追加してください。権限をより多くな人に与えるため[投票しよう](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0-%E6%8A%95%E7%A5%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)!

Comment: 必要なタグが無ければメタで提案というやり方に賛成します。

Comment: 確かに対策としてはメタで提案というのは現状の手段なのでしょうが、それで良いのかは個人としては疑問が残ります...

Comment: @rizaudo メタでの提案で不都合はありますか？

Comment: @tomute メタでの提案でも良いのですが、どのようなものでも毎回タグを作る時に一つメタで議論の場を作る必要があるのかという疑問があります。現状の手段ではそれがベストなのは理解していますが、私が追記した手段などは取れないものでしょうか？

Comment: @rizaudo 現状の案がベストとは言えないかも知れませんが、導入反対の票がある程度ありますので、まずは現状で様子を見て不都合な面が多くなってきた場合に、再度討議するという事で如何でしょうか？

Comment: @tomute そうですね、使うタグが無いため、熱くなってしまいました。問題がもう少し大きくなった時にまた提起したいと思います。 ありがとうございました。

Comment: @rizaudo 至急タグが必要という場合にはチャット等でリクエストして頂いても結構ですので、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

重要なタグをMetaで討議して予め利用可能にしておくという方法もあるかもしれません。

例えば`d`, `dart`, `lua`, `assembler`, `tcl`, `delphi` などは現在タグがありませんが、言語自体の質問をしたいときに他のタグを付けるのが難しいと思います。

Comment: h2so5 さんが本質問に対するコメントのほうで書かれたMeta SE の質問に対する回答(@JoachimSauerさんによる)では，言語名かアルゴリズムタグを使えば少なくともひとつは不適でないタグをつけられるはず，ひとつでもタグがつけば誰かがより良いタグ付けをしてくれることが期待できるということが（導入の必要がないとする）論拠のひとつとしてあげられています．主要な言語などを予めカバーしておくのは効果的のようにおもいますし，逆に現状ないのはかなり不便．事前に討議してまとまった量のタグを追加しておくのはかなりよい案だと思います．

Answer (score 0):

自分は賛成です。

いくつかの状態について考えてみます。

---

#### 自分の求めているタグがない場合

1. 適当にタグを付ける
2. 質問自体を諦める

1.慣れていれば簡単な方法です。タグが間違っているなどとコメントを貰うよりも先に**タグが変更されることを知っている**からです。
2.慣れていれば諦める理由はありません。ですが初めての人はこちらのほうが簡単です。他のタブを開きコピペでほかのサイトに質問すればいいだけです。

---

#### 適当なタグを付けたために起こるリスクです。

1. 質問が適切な回答者のもとに届かない
2. 編集者がタグを編集する必要がある
3. タグが少ないほど検索されにくくなる。
4. 間違ったタグのまま長く放置される

4.は何日発見されないか確認したかったのですが、
[指令統制スキーム以外のソフトウェアアーキテクチャ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2888/%E6%8C%87%E4%BB%A4%E7%B5%B1%E5%88%B6%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3)
は`architecture`タグが無いために今でも`c`のタグです。
今日明日で回答はとまるでしょう。

---

#### タグ無しを付けたために起こると予測されうる現象です。

1. タグ検索により編集すべき一覧が手に入る
2. 質問や回答でさえない人が編集によって信用度を得ることが出来る。
3. 編集経験豊富な人がタグをつけやすくなる。新しいタグ発見する可能性が高くなる。
4. 強引なタグ付けが減少し検索精度向上が狙える。

これらは全て負の利益ではありません。また、タグ付けに際して質問文を読まなければならないので健全な運営が期待できます。