# 「タグの作成」権限の範囲とヘルプ センターの説明の改善に関する疑問と要望

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 完了, タグ, 権限

### 前提

スタック・オーバーフローに以下の質問が投稿されました。これは[編集履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/57951/revisions)からも分かるとおり、タグ名として `laravel` ではなく `ｌａｒａｖｅｌ` が使用されていました。

- [ｌａｒａｖｅｌ - LaravelのSimple QR CODE　generate(' ')のの中に　https://example/kaiiin/show/{id} のURLを入れたい - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57951/laravel%E3%81%AEsimple-qr-code-generate-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB-https-example-kaiiin-show-id-%E3%81%AEurl%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5)
- [Wayback Machine によるウェブアーカイブバージョン](https://web.archive.org/web/20190909153518/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57951/laravel%E3%81%AEsimple-qr-code-generate-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB-https-example-kaiiin-show-id-%E3%81%AEurl%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5)

---

### 質問と要望

#### 質問. 「タグの作成」権限が必要な場面は？

まず、この質問者は質問投稿時での信頼度が `1` となっています。また、ヘルプ センターの説明から、私はタグの作成には[信頼度が少なくとも 150 必要](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)であると認識していました。

> #### タグの作成
>
> 権限の種類: 作成権限
>   授与資格:信用度 150 点
>
> #### タグの作成とは?
>
> タグとは、あなたの質問をよく似た他の質問と一緒に分類するキーワードまたはラベルのことです。新しいタグを作成する場合、それまでに (すくなくともこのサイトで) 誰も質問しなかったトピックの質問をしていることになります。

しかし、**実際には信頼度が `1` にも関わらず**、当該質問者は質問に新しいタグ (`ｌａｒａｖｅｌ`) を紐付けすることが出来ています。自身が質問を投稿する場合 (もしくは特定の条件下) では、この権限が必要ないのでしょうか？

#### 要望. 全角文字のタグが使用出来ることをヘルプ センターの説明で明確にしたい

現状、全角文字のタグはメタを中心にいくつか存在します (例. [バグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0), [タグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0), [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0), etc.)。そのため、タグ名には全角文字が使用出来るものだと思っていました。しかし、[ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)にはそのような記述はなく、以下のような**「全角文字のみのタグが使用出来る」ことが分からない**説明となっています。

> #### 新しいタグの作成方法は?
>
> 質問と一緒に新しいタグを入力するだけで作成されます。新しいタグを作成する場合はタグについて以下のこと念頭に置いてください。
>
> - 25 文字未満でなければなりません
> - 文字セット `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.` を使用しなければなりません

具体例に既存のタグ名を挙げると、上記引用部の 2 つの条件によれば、 [タグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0) というタグは 25 文字未満ですが、**該当する文字セットを一度も使用していない**ため、**作成出来ないタグ**であるはずです。

このように、全角文字が使用出来る動作が仕様通りなのか、そうではないのかが分かりづらく、もし前者であればヘルプ センターの文章を変更する、もし後者であれば全角文字のみで構成されたタグを修正する、などの対処を要望します。

個人的には、タグの読みやすさを考慮すると、ひらがな、カタカナや漢字が使用出来るほうが便利なため、ヘルプ センターの説明を変更し、 (一部の？) 全角文字もタグに使用可能だと明示するほうが良いと考えています。

---

### 関連投稿

#### 質問に関連する投稿

- [タグの提案: タグが現在無い質問用のタグの作成 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1547)
  この投稿の質問文に「タグを作成出来る人がそう多く居ません」と書かれていることから、「タグ作成の作成」権限自体はどこかで機能しているようだとわかります。

#### 要望に関連する投稿

- [全角英数字をタグに使えないようにしてほしい - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2405)
  「これがかなり治しにくい」とのコメントがあることから、現在でも全角文字のタグ名を禁止することは難しいかもしれません。
- [英語タグから日本語タグへのシノニムを作りたい - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2542)

Comment: よく見ると  `Ｌａｒａｖｅｌ` タグでのタグ説明文が `Laravel` タグに関するものになっている([参考](https://web.archive.org/web/20190909153531/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%8c%ef%bd%81%ef%bd%92%ef%bd%81%ef%bd%96%ef%bd%85%ef%bd%8c))。もしかして、タグ名が全角、半角で区別されないから、「タグの作成」ではなく「既存のタグの紐付け」として扱われている...？

Comment: おそらく新しいタグを作成したのではなく、シノニム扱いされたか、過去に `Ｌａｒａｖｅｌ` というタグを使ってしまった人がいて、そのときに作成されたタグが発掘されたのではないかという予感がします。編集履歴から `Ｌａｒａｖｅｌ` のポップアップを見ると `Laravel` のそれになっているので、内部的にこっそりシノニムになっているのかも……？　その上で全角版をタグに設定できてしまうバグなのかもしれません。

Comment: ふむむ、なるほど...。昨日作成したばかりの `jquery-mobile` タグでも、全角文字での検索時に [`laravel` タグと同様の現象が発生した](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%8a%ef%bd%91%ef%bd%95%ef%bd%85%ef%bd%92%ef%bd%99-%ef%bd%8d%ef%bd%8f%ef%bd%82%ef%bd%89%ef%bd%8c%ef%bd%85)ので、確かに内部的にシノニム扱いになっているの可能性が高いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### タグの作成の権限

> しかし、実際には信頼度が 1 にも関わらず、当該質問者は質問に新しいタグ (ｌａｒａｖｅｌ) を紐付けすることが出来ています。自身が質問を投稿する場合 (もしくは特定の条件下) では、この権限が必要ないのでしょうか？

信用度 1 ではタグが作成できないことを確認しました。ヘルプページの記述で正しいと思われます。cubickさんの回答の通り、全角アルファベットの使用による現象と思われます。（投稿時にタグの検証を追加するべきかも知れません。これに関しては、いずれ別途議論する予定です。）

#### 使用可能な文字種の記述

> ヘルプ センターの説明を変更し、 (一部の？) 全角文字もタグに使用可能だと明示するほうが良いと考えています。

[『ヘルプ記事「タグの作成」の文字数と文字セットの記述を修正して下さい』](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3966/)にてお願いし、記述を変更しました。

Answer (score 4):

まず、該当の質問は私が既に修正してしまったのですが、「タグの作成」についてはsupaさんが考えているのとは別のバグである可能性があります。

例えば "Python" に関してメインで使用されているのは半角の[python](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)ですが、わざと[ｐｙｔｈｏｎ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%90%ef%bd%99%ef%bd%94%ef%bd%88%ef%bd%8f%ef%bd%8e)のように全角で指定すると、タグwikiの説明は[python](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)と同じものが表示され、質問は何も表示されません。

試しにログアウト状態で質問を投稿しようとした場合、新しいタグを作成しようとすると権限で怒られますが、既存タグの全角表記、[ｐｙｔｈｏｎ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%90%ef%bd%99%ef%bd%94%ef%bd%88%ef%bd%8f%ef%bd%8e)などの場合には同一とみなされているようです。

**(追記)**
全角英数の扱いに関しては、下記のメタ投稿での [コメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2405/%e5%85%a8%e8%a7%92%e8%8b%b1%e6%95%b0%e5%ad%97%e3%82%92%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0%e3%81%ab%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bb%e3%81%97%e3%81%84#comment1837_2405) によると仕様バグ？の様な感じです。
随分前に直そうとしたけど、結局そのまま進展が無い状態でしょうかね。

[全角英数字をタグに使えないようにしてほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2405)

---

ヘルプセンターの説明に関しては、メインサイトでも全角のタグ、[正規表現](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e6%ad%a3%e8%a6%8f%e8%a1%a8%e7%8f%be)などが普通に使われているので、現状のヘルプが単に英語の内容を直訳したままだからだと思います。

「全角も使える」と明記してもいいのですが、そうすると「25文字未満て半角換算？全角文字の場合は？」などはっきりさせないといけないことがいくつか出てくるのかなと。