# ヘルプ記事「タグの作成」の文字数と文字セットの記述を修正して下さい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

[権限「タグの作成」のヘルプ記事](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)の翻訳を修正して下さい。

あるいは、該当のページをモデレーター権限で編集可能にしていただくのでも構いません。その場合、モデレーターチームで翻訳を更新します。

原文:

> - must be no longer than 35 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

現在の翻訳:

> - 25 文字未満でなければなりません
> - 文字セット `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.` を使用しなければなりません

修正案:

> - 35文字以内でなければなりません
> - 全角アルファベットは使用せずに、文字セット `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.` もしくは日本語を使用しなければなりません

日本語文字列（漢字）でも35文字使えることを確認済です。

関連: [「タグの作成」権限の範囲とヘルプ センターの説明の改善に関する疑問と要望](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3084/3054)

Comment: ヘルプセンターは SE staff の方にお願いするとモデレーター限定で編集可能に変えてくださいます。この投稿に特に反対がないようであれば chat 等でお願いして編集可能にしてもらえば mjy さんが更新できるようになるはず……です。

Comment: nit: 「および日本語」のところ、「もしくは日本語」だと如何でしょうか？　日本語を必ず含めないといけないとは読めないようにしたいです。

Comment: 「もしくは」にしました。文面の提案などをもう数日待ってから進めようと思います。

Comment: 数日前にモデレータの方が編集できるよう設定変更の依頼をCMの方にかけましたが、現在も設定が変えられないようです。(おそらくHTMLで書かれていると思われる)テキストの送付依頼も同時に行っていますが入手できないため、この問題についてはコミュニティマネジメントチームがエンジニアリングチームへ調査を依頼しました。

Comment: この記事に関しましてはモデレーター専用で編集可能に設定を変更することが難しい状況だったため、代わりにCMツールを活用して編集作業を進めました。Mod editableになる記事とならない記事が混在するようです‍♀️。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

修正案の通りに変更され、反映を確認いたしました。

[image: 35文字]

---

追記 (2024/01/30)
インラインコードのバッククォートがそのまま表示されてしまっていたため、ヘルプ記事を HTML から Markdown に書き換え、本日サイトへの反映を確認いたしました。

[image: HTML -> Markdown]

Comment: ご対応お疲れ様です。インラインコードのバッククォートがそのまま表示されているようですが、これは一時的なもの（CMツールを使った通常と異なる編集によるもの）という認識でよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @supa 感謝いたします！@mjy さんも先ほどCMの方に伝えられたところですが、日本語話者が直接編集できるように、私の方からもテキストを送付してもらえないか再度依頼してみました。もしも入手できましたら、[以前に作業くださったものを参考に‍♀️](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3391/6)HTML -> Markdown の書き換えを行いたいと思います。