# 全てのヘルプページをモデレーター権限で編集可能にするか、通常の翻訳対象文字列として下さい

Tags: 機能の要求, 調査中, 翻訳, ヘルプ

翻訳が必要な全てのヘルプページをモデレーター権限で編集可能にして下さい（現在はモデレーターが編集可能なページと、そうでないものが混在しています）。

あるいは、編集不可になっているページの文章を、通常の翻訳フローで扱えるように、翻訳対象文字列にして下さい。

#### 理由

日本語版の[ヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)の翻訳の一部は古くなっており、原文に追随できていない箇所が有ります。現在、こういった翻訳の問題に対処するには過大な負担が有ります。

具体的には、修正箇所毎にメタサイトで質問を投稿し、Stack Exchange社にエスカレーションし、細部をチャットでやりとりする必要が有ります。現実的に、これを続けるリソースはユーザー側にもStack Exchange社側にも有りません。簡便な方法が必要です。

ユーザーからの指摘がメタサイトで行なわれるとしても、以降の作業をモデレーターが行なえるか、他の箇所と同じく通常の翻訳システムで扱えるなら、それは許容可能な負担と考えます。

メタサイトでの作業方法をより洗練させる方法も考えられますが、翻訳作業中にメタサイトの更新がそれで埋まってしまうなどの問題が有ります。基本的に、日々の翻訳作業を掲示板やチャットに類するシステムで行なうのは困難です。

#### 他サイトの既存の要望との違い

今回のお願いは、あくまで翻訳を原文に追随させ、このサイトのユーザーも他のサイトのユーザーと同じ内容のヘルプが読めるようにするためのものです。全てのヘルプをこのサイト独自の内容にカスタマイズしたい、ということでは有りません。Meta Stack Exchangeにおいて出されている[類似した要望](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279879/)とは、必要とする理由が異なります。

このサイト独自の内容をヘルプページに盛り込みたい、という要望も有りますが、それは別に許可をいただく予定ですので、それとは分けて可否を判断いただきたいと思います。

#### 対象のページ

一般ユーザーが閲覧可能な全てのヘルプページを、編集可能、あるいは翻訳対象文字列にしていただけると助かります。閲覧に権限が必要なページは原文を英語版サイトで確認できませんし、翻訳システムに登録してもいけないはずですから、翻訳できませんので対象外です。

[「英語版サイトの質問や回答を、日本語に翻訳しても良いですか？ 」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english) というページは、このサイトオリジナルの内容であり、翻訳では有りませんが、あえて別の扱いをせずとも良いと思います。

Comment: 補足：今まで編集したいヘルプページが生まれたときは都度都度 chat で SE staff の方にメンションして変更してもらっていました。なので修正箇所ごとに SE 社と連絡をとるようなことはしておらず、もっぱら新しいページを翻訳したくなったときに編集権限だけもらって後はメタでコミュニティ主導で進めていた形です。

Comment: @nekketsuuu なるほど。前回の作業( https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3966 ) の経験では、そうはいかなかったので、いつの時点かで変わったのかも知れませんね。

Comment: ヘルプ記事によってはモデレーターによる編集を可能にするのが難しいものがあるとは以前から聞いていたので、そういう話かもしれません。https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3966#comment4092_3966 によると「Mod editableになる記事とならない記事が混在するようです」とのことです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 他のサイトでヘルプを編集するのは、サイト毎のカスタマイズをする場合だけでしょうから、編集権限付与の可否もそのページのカスタマイズの可否に準じているんじゃないかと想像します。
もしそうなら、日本語版ではカスタマイズでは無く、翻訳を行なっているので、判断基準を変えて欲しい所です。

Comment: 自分が聞いたのは Markdown ではない方法で実装されているページは少し難しいというやつですね。詳しいところは SE staffs に伺ってみないと分からないですが。

Comment: プログラム的に編集不可のページは別の扱いになっているのなら、他の箇所と同じように翻訳対象文字列にしてもらう方が簡単かも知れません。
それでも構わないので、要望に加えました。
ただ、「○○あるいは□□」といった要望が正しくStack Exchange社に伝わるか不安です。
解り難いと思われる箇所が有れば、編集で改善していただければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

SOja サイトユーザーも、英語版ユーザーと同じ内容のヘルプ記事を読めるようにするため、翻訳の反映プロセスを改善することに賛成します。以下の情報は、ユーザーのみなさまと SE Inc. スタッフへの情報共有のために記載いたします。私の知る範囲での情報となります。（もしもモデレータさんと私の見え方が違う場合にはどうぞお知らせください。）

#### 翻訳対象ページと編集方法

**権限とバッジ**

- [権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) 画面に表示されているの各ページ（[アクセス解析の閲覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)など）は、Mod editable 設定に変更**不可**でした。
- [バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) は、Traducir から入力し反映されるようです。
  例：https://ja.traducir.win/strings/8516

**Markdown**

- [Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) は、現時点では Mod editable です。モデレーターの方のみ、左下に編集ボタンが表示されているかと。
- [Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) は、Traducir から入力し反映されるようです。
  例：https://ja.traducir.win/strings/6492

**その他**

- その他の一般的なヘルプページは、Mod editable 設定に変更可能と思われますが、CM にページの設定変更を依頼する必要があります。

**Traducir から入力しても反映されない場合**

Traducir から入力後承認してもサイトに反映されない場合、Dev Block がかけられている可能性があります。その場合は、CM から Dev への連絡が必要です。

**新しく追加されるヘルプ記事について**

最近最も新しく追加された記事として [AI Policy](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) があげられますが、こちらは現時点で Mod editable です。以前[レビューキュー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues)が追加された時は  Mod editable で編集が開始されなかったため、何らかの変更があったようにも見えるのですが、確かなことはわかりません。

Comment: 権限のページも、[たぶんこの翻訳文字列で](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4091)翻訳可のようです。
AI Policyは当初（今も？）各サイト毎に選択可能とされていたと思うので、カスタマイズ可能にしてあるのかなと想像します。
とりあえず、このままエスカレーションいたしますが、もし必要であれば対象のページのURLをリストアップしますのでお知らせ下さい。

Comment: 権限の各ページという意味でしたので、編集いたしました。privileges/site-analytics、privileges/trusted-user などです。